# pytorch I don't know how to define multiple models

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I want to use two different models in pytorch. Therefore, I executed the following code, but I cannot successfully run the second model. How can I do this?

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(2, 64)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(64, 3)

    def forward(self, x):   
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)  
        x = self.linear2(x)

        return x
                
class Model2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(2, 64)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(64, 1)

    def forward(self, x):   
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)  
        x = self.linear2(x)

        return x
                
net = Model()
net2 = Model2()
```

### erorr

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

```
/tmp/ipykernel_477/2280223066.py in <module>
     26 
     27 net = Model()
---> 28 net2 = Model2()

/tmp/ipykernel_477/2280223066.py in __init__(self)
     14 class Model2(nn.Module):
     15     def __init__(self):
---> 16         super(Model, self).__init__()
     17         self.linear1 = nn.Linear(2, 64)
     18         self.linear2 = nn.Linear(64, 1)
```

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Comment: In line 16, You cannot call ```super``` with ```Model``` class which is the previous class that you made, it can be your own class ```Model2```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are calling super(Model, self).**init**() in line 16 instead of super(Model2, self).**init**(). You have to change the name of the model to match the name of the current class every time. Line 3 runs because Model is actually the name of the class in that case.